# How to set the same header in the ToC?

Tags: fancyhdr

I want to set the same header of my book in the table of contents (ToC), list of figures, liste of tables, .... I have a problem with fancyhdr package. The header chosen in this example is not set at the top of my ToC. How to get the same header in the all document?

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Also, the page number of the first page of the table of contents and chapters is not in bold like in the header, how to make it bold?

How to remove the page number at the bottom of the page?

This is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%------------------------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1] 
{\markboth{\small\textcolor{blue}{\textsc{\chaptername}\ 
\thechapter\;}\textbullet \sffamily \ #1}{}} 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1] 
{\markright{\small\sffamily\thesection\hspace{10pt}#1}{}}
%\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\normalsize\bfseries\thepage}  
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark} 
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

%------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\chapter{Test 1 }
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{Section}

This is page 2.
\end{document}
%------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page style in the first page of every chapter (toc is also a seperate chapter) is `plain`. This is done by issuing a `\thispagestyle{plain}` command in the kernel code.

If you want to get the same header and footer throughout the document, you can redefine the `plain` pagestyle to `fancy` style in the following simple way:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
```

See the [documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) of `fancyhdr` package for more details. (Especially section 11 about redefining page style `plain`)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1] 
{\markboth{\small\textcolor{blue}{\textsc{\chaptername}\ 
\thechapter\;}\textbullet \sffamily \ #1}{}} 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1] 
{\markright{\small\sffamily\thesection\hspace{10pt}#1}{}}
%\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\normalsize\bfseries\thepage}  
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark} 
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark} 
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}%
  {\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}\markboth{\sffamily\contentsname}{}}{}{}
\makeatother
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}

%------------------------------------
\begin{document}


\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{Test 1 }
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{Section}

This is page 2.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work, I put it where?

Comment: For example, before the `\begin{document}`

Comment: Stephen the TOC header is in capital letters, it is not the same style as the chapter header in \sffamily

Comment: I have edited the answer.@Gallagher

Comment: This is what I am looking for @Stephen, thank you so much.